# How to add log4net appender in runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

How do I add an extra log appender in runtime? (all pre-existing appenders must keep on working)
I'm trying it this way:

```
        var layout = new PatternLayout("%utcdate %-5level - %message%newline");
        layout.ActivateOptions();
        _log4netAppender = new FileAppender
            {
                Layout = layout,
                File = logFilePath,
            };
        _log4netAppender.ActivateOptions();
        BasicConfigurator.Configure(_log4netAppender);
```

but it doesn't write anything to the file.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should also add the appender to a logger.
Take a look here [Adding Appenders programmatically](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4net-user/200602.mbox/%3CDDEB64C8619AC64DBC074208B046611C769745@kronos.neoworks.co.uk%3E)

If the logger you are using is, for example `ILog logger` do:

`((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)logger.Logger).AddAppender(appender)`

Comment: It didn't work for me.
I was trying to output logs to Nunit console and `BasicConfigurator.Configure();` did the trick.

Answer (score 6):

```cs
var patternLayout = new log4net.Layout.PatternLayout
{
    ConversionPattern = "%date %level %message%newline"
};
patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

var rollingFileAppender = new log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender
{
    File = "MyApp.log",
    Layout = patternLayout
};
rollingFileAppender.ActivateOptions();

var hierarchy = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)log4net.LogManager.GetRepository();
hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(rollingFileAppender);
hierarchy.Root.Level = log4net.Core.Level.All; // Default is Debug

log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(hierarchy);
```