# Is <param> tag ever supposed to work with <logger> or <root>?

Tags: apache, log4net, log4net-configuration

From this [Apache documentation page](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#loggers), I understand that the `<param>` tag is supposed to work with the `<logger>` tag, but apparently it doesn't.

For example, this:

```
<logger name="LogTest">
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    <param name="File" value="f:\dev\logfile"/>
</logger>
```

...produces the following error:

> XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Cannot find Property [File] to set object on [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.DefaultLoggerFactory+LoggerImpl]. Source: log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works just fine, but `Logger` doesn't *have* a `File` property, as the message correctly says. That's a property of the *appender*. You can't use one single appender (`FileAppender` in this case) to write to multiple files. Either parameterize the `FileAppender`, or split to multiple appenders.

Comment: If all you want to do is configure the location of the file, just configure the `FileAppender` directly, not the logger. The only thing you'd configure on the logger is the `level` and the `appender`, not much else. `param` is only there for completeness, in case you have a custom logger class that does have other properties (which would be a rare thing).

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch that it is told about "logger" parameters and not about FileAppender's. Thanx for pointing. Also, I understood now that I can't use this as the "factory" for multiple FileAppenders with different file paths, but rather have to clone appenders in config. That's sad. Thank you.

Comment: If the configuration is too cumbersome, you can always add appenders and/or loggers programmatically. See, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833362/).

Comment: Thanks, I know that. But unfortunately my setup is the zillions of configurations and any of them can be anything.