# How to stop log4net from logging and release the last file

Tags: c#, winforms, log4net

I'm using log4net in C# Win Form App and I have start/stop toggle button -

When I click "start" the log4net config are loaded and the log file is created - That is working.

But now I want to add the option to click "stop" button, for stopping the logger and of course release the file so I could open it with `openFileDialog` that I have in my app for reading the log file text with `StreamReader` to show the log file on a multiline `textbox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `Threshold` during runtime. To stop logging set it to `Off`. I have already shown how this works in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52698445/how-set-default-appender-in-web-config/52705620#52705620).

Comment: Hi. I stoped the logging as you wrote but the problem is that also after that, the last log file that was created is "readonly" and I cant open it with my openFileDialog

Comment: Yes, the log-File is readonly, but you can read it with e.g. notepad.exe. What do you want tp do exactly with your file?

Comment: i want the option to load the file after recording with openFileDialog and use StreamReader to show the log file on a multiline textbox

Answer (score 0):

Stopping log4net during **runtime** requires modifying its config file's:

```
<level value="ALL" />
```

to

```
<level value="INFO" />
```

If you can't change the config file you should define a proxy for `log.debug()`:

```
static public class LogDebugProxy
{
    static public bool LogDebug = false;
    static public void debug(log4net.ILog log)
    {
        if (LogDebug)
            log.debug();
    }
}
```

Then replace `log.debug()` with `LogDebugProxy.debug(log)` in your entire project.

Now, you can Enable / Disable it by it's proxy.

Comment: Hi. the problem is that the last log file is still readonly and i cant open it with openFileDialog

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to read the `log4net` log-file:

```
            string text;
            var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\logs\yourLogFile.log", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(this, text);
            }
```